# Select, open and split a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to reuse the below code to select, open and split a file. The code opens a dialog box and the file is selected, after that it looks like it is doing something but it terminates with no errors, but the split never happen. Am I missing something?

```
import os
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
root = Tk()
filename = askopenfilename(title="Hi slect a file")    
root.destroy()         

filename_n = 0
done = False
with open (filename) as in_file: 
     while not done: #loop over output file names
        with open(f"out{filename_n}.dat", "w") as out_file: 
            while not done: 
                try:
                    line = next(in_file).strip() 
                except StopIteration:
                    done = True
                    break
                if "EOD" in line: 
                    break
                else:
                    out_file.write(line + '\n') 
            filename_n += 1 #increment output file name integer
```

Comment: Could you be more specific on what "split a file" means? There are many possibilities.   We should not have to read the code to figure that out.

Comment: I tested that code and it just rewrite input file to out0.dat file - could you please explain what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @JakubBujny Did you have any `EOD` lines in your input file?

Comment: [Here's your code running on some sample input on repl.it.](https://repl.it/repls/SiennaAmusedRepository) It splits the file into what I think is exactly what you wanted. If that output isn't right, explain what's wrong with it. If that output _is_ right, but you have _different_ input that it gets wrong, show us that input. And also, remove all the tkinter stuff that isn't relevant to your problem. More generally, see [mcve] in the help for what to include in a question to make it answerable.

Comment: Ahh I didn't - I added EOD and it works fine

Comment: As a side note: `if "EOD" in line: #more robust than 'if line == "EOD\n":'` is a pretty weird comment. Do you really want a line like `I FOUND A GEODE` to count as a split? If not, then your `in` makes it _less_ robust. Maybe what you're looking for is `if line.strip() == "EOD"`? But without knowing what problem you were trying to solve in the first place, that's just a guess.

Comment: I has a file that includes few thousands of line, at the end of each batch of lines there is an EOD mark, I'm using those marks to output a new file at each mark.
Just to mention the code was working fine until I added the tkinter part, trying to select a file using a dialog box, if I take that out it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is my fault - sorry, the code is working fine, but the output was written to the script folder and I overlooked it. I modified the code to include an output directory selection. Here is the working code.

```
import os
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
root = Tk()
filename = askopenfilename(title="Please slect a file")   #Select input file
path = filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir=os.getcwd(), title="Please select a folder:") #Select output directory
root.destroy()          #Close the dialog box

filename_n = 0          
done = False
with open (filename) as in_file: 
    while not done: 
            with open(os.path.join(path,f"out{filename_n}.dat"), "w") as out_file: 
             while not done: 
                try:
                    line = next(in_file).strip() 
                except StopIteration:
                    done = True
                    break
                if "EOD" in line: 
                    break
                else:
                    out_file.write(line + '\n') 
            filename_n += 1
```